# Updating the element in the link function propagates the change across all instances of the directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is the skeleton of my directive:

```
define(function () {
  return [
    '$deps',
    function ($deps) {

      return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function ($scope, $el, attrs) {
          attrs.$observe('attr-name', function (attrValue) {
            // process the attrvalue, and come up with the href
            $el.attr('href', processedResult);
          });
        }
      };
    }
  ]
})
```

Problem being, when I use the `$el.attr()`, it is updating all the instances of the directive (all the tags get the href); why might this be happening?

Comment: Are you using jQuery ? How about a fiddle ?

Comment: Are you passing a tag name or an element ID to your `$el` variable?

Comment: @mwilson: This is an Angular-specific question. `$el` is ot passed by the OP, but by Angular's Dependency-Injection system.

Comment: Hard to answer without more of the code. Could you reproduce it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Definitely, plz create a fiddle/plnkr that reproduces the issue

Comment: Hello everyone, thanks for trying to help. Right now I figure that the actual directive is not the only problem, there's something else in my setup which is interfering with the hrefs when the route changes. I will try to track it down and if I can't I'll work on reproducing the problem on plnkr.